# Generate the iphone push notification using titanium with php server

Tags: php, ios, titanium, apple-push-notifications

I have to implement ios push notification using titanium framework.

If i have implementing with the ACS accelerator server., am getting the push notification.But if i have implementing with the php script., i did n't receive a notification. am getting the following error:

```
{"meta":{"code":422,
         "status":"fail",
         "message":"Missing fields. Required: to_ids or friends",
         "method_name":"Notify"}}"
```

Please give me a solution.

I have followed the [tutorial](http://iosmuncher.blogspot.in/2012/06/implementing-apns-in-titanium-start-to.html?showComment=1416572923193#c732015998466094803)

**EDIT :**

I have created the pem file. may be the issue in this file . How can i create a pem file and how can i verify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As am given the pem file path is wrong. That's what am getting the "Request Failed" error. Now it is working fine.

Comment: if anyone facing this issue., please you can check with your pem file and pem file path.And also check whether the port 2195 is open or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send the notification ***to all the user/tokens subscribed to the channel*** before checking the rest try to change:

```
$c_opt[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]  = "channel=".$channel."&payload=".$json;
```

In:

```
$c_opt[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]  = "channel=".$channel."&payload=".$json.'&to_ids="everyone"';
```

You have an error message from the notify.json method and (From the notify.json [acs rest api docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/PushNotifications-method-notify)):

> Specify either friends or to_ids. Enterprise users can also specify where. **One of these parameters must be used.** These parameters cannot be used simultaneously.

And later:

> to_ids: String
>
> Comma-separated list of user IDs to send the notification to users who are subscribed to the specified channel. Up to 1000 users can be specified.
> You cannot use this parameter when using a location query with the where parameter.
> **Application admins can set this parameter to everyone to send to all devices subscribed to the channel.**
> If you are using the web interface, you do not need to specify this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your `pem` file with text editor.
2. Check your `pem` file type whether development or distribution.
3. Also check your bundel identifier shows correclty.